# Is this Racket macro written in an idiomatic style?

Tags: macros, racket

My son and I are learning Racket together and are building a very simple text-based adventure for use directly from the REPL. So, for example, the player can type `(go 'north)` or `(take 'apple)`.

After getting some basic stuff working, my son thought that quoting the noun was a bit of a pain (strangely, the parens don't bother him!), and so we hacked around with macros for a bit and we did get something working but it required an explicit function and a corresponding macro e.g.

```
    (define (do-take item) ...)
    (define-syntax (take stx)
      (define item (cadr (syntax->datum stx)))
      (datum->syntax stx `(do-take ',item)))
```

I figured we could do better than this, so I read around a bit more and came up with this:

```
    (require (for-syntax racket/syntax))
    (define-syntax (define-verb stx)
     (syntax-case stx ()
       [(_ (verb noun) body-first body-rest ...)
        (with-syntax ([verb-fun (format-id stx "do-~a" #'verb)])
          #'(begin
              (define-syntax-rule (verb noun) (verb-fun 'noun))
              (define (verb-fun noun) body-first body-rest ...)))]))
```

So now, we can write `(define-verb (take item) ...)` and the player at the REPL can type `(take apple)`.

My question is whether, given what we want to achieve, this is a reasonable approach or whether there a more simple / idiomatic way to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the main thing I would recommend doing is using the [`syntax/parse`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax/stxparse.html) library. It has more tools for parsing syntax. You can even use forms like [`define-syntax-parser`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax/Defining_Simple_Macros.html?q=define-syntax-parser#%28form._%28%28lib._syntax%2Fparse%2Fdefine..rkt%29._define-syntax-parser%29%29) to make your macro even more concise. Rewriting your code using `syntax/parse` (dropping that one line because it doesn't seem to be doing anything), your macro would look like this:

```
#lang racket
(require syntax/parse/define
         (for-syntax syntax/parse racket/syntax))
(define-syntax-parser define-verb
  [(_ (verb:id noun) body ...+)
   (define/syntax-parse verb-fun (format-id stx "do-~a" #'verb))
   #'(begin
       (define-simple-macro (verb noun) (verb-fun 'noun))
       (define (verb-fun noun) body ...))])
```

This gives you a few nice things above the example you gave:

- the `:id` ensures that `verb` is a literal identifier, rather than an expression.
- the `...+` means you only need to have one `body` pattern, rather than two.
- Using `define/syntax-parse` means your code does not get more indented than `with-syntax`. (Although this one is a matter of preference.)

Comment: The `syntax-quote` needs to be over a `begin` with the `define-syntax-rule` for the macro to work.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you're saying here.

Comment: You comment about being unsure what the `define-syntax-rule` is for. It should be in a `#'(begin ...)`. Sorry I was unclear!

Comment: Ah, okay. Well in that case I will update my answer (and the question) accordingly. Thanks. :)